# Where to find all/most variants of a glyth?

Tags: character-variant

As far as I know, for one glyth (ex.: 御) there many variant forms.

Some sources list 䘖䘘禦 as variants, [others](http://glyphwiki.org/wiki/u5fa1) say that all of the glyths in string 御䘖䘘䢩禦衘馭 are variants of 御.

Is there a reliable source where I can find all (or most of) the variants for a given glyth. I need only CHARS, that is those you can type with in modern PC.

Comment: If you were to learn these variants of characters, I would suggest not, since no one is using these variants in the modern days and even a native speaker have little knowledge of them. If you were just curious, then go ahead and have fun!

Comment: No, I need them for the app. User inputs a glyth and receives some info. Problem is user can input any variant of a given glyth and I need to know them all. Well, those you can type at least (unicode codepoints).

Comment: Unicode.org release a version at about June every year, Chinese glyphs covered too, its Unihan data in xml can be extracted with a program, then you can list all variants by SQL.
https://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=御

Comment: I hope that you have a detailed understanding of what *variant* actually means. Just with the example you posted, 御 is a variant of both 馭 and 禦, but 馭 is definitely not a variant of 禦.

Comment: I suspected that. :( But, well.. is there a way for machine to undestand this? I guess not. So, in my app they will have to be variants of each over :(

Comment: Yes I know about Unicode.org but variant field is poor there. Not much variants there

Comment: What kind of app are you making? I don't think people would input any variant ... at least I won't input any variant other than the original character. And by the way, variant mapping is not a one-on-one mapping. It is more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

i would use 教育部異體字字典:

http://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/home.do

it's authoritative, and most comprehensive.

eg 御 (u+5fa1), it listed 37 variants :)

http://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/word_attribute.rbt?quote_code=QTAxMjk1

have fun :)

Comment: This is .... intimidating at least. Too much variants. Thanks for the link, but it doesn't list those glyth as chars (unicode characters) instead it show them as images.

Comment: @coobit; A lot of these glyph variants _don't even have_ Unicode codepoints, and a lot of fonts cannot display them anyway.

Comment: Yes, I know. So I need to stick to all codable glyths... I need this for the software I'm working on.

Comment: @coobit, an app for variants? may i say, it's a mission impossible, if not extremely difficult. as the example 御 shown, some variants do not yet have a unicode code point. this situation might change gradually, into the supplementary ideographic plane. secondarily, you need a font that mapped glyph to code point. the arial unicode ms has 50000+, the noto has 65000+; which is inadequate for displaying all variants.

Comment: Of course it's not about variants. I need only those variants which are already coded into unicode. I know what you are talking about. Thanks for advise :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found even more unicode variants for 御

圄敔禦衘䘘䢩馭御䘖

Well, that sucks!

source:
http://tls.uni-hd.de/main/basic_ch_char.lasso
That's a pretty thorough DataBase, I must admit.